Neovim permission issue (~/.local) after installing on mac
Just installed neovim on my mac (macOS: Sonoma 14.5, Chip: Apple M2) using homebrew. When I tried to start neovim I get the following error (I replaced my real username with UserName in the path below):
Error detected while processing /opt/homebrew/Cellar/neovim/0.10.0/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/rplugin.vim[68]..function <SNR>12_LoadRemotePlugins[1]..<SNR>12_GetManifest[1]..<SNR>12_GetManifestPath:
line   11:
E739: Cannot create directory /Users/UserName/.local/share: permission denied

To solve this issue I understand that I would need to grant the User "UserName" write permission to the ~/.local directory (probably with sudo: sudo chmod +w ~/.local), but is this safe thing to do? I don't see this step in any neovim installation tutorial I have seen so far.

You should already have full access to everything in your ~ (home) folder. It's your own user home folder. What does ls -al ~/.local show? You might have used sudo somewhere along the way with homebrew and screwed up your permissions?

Oh okay. Where could I have screwed up the persmissions? While installing homebrew?  This is what the command shows me:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  staff    96 May 26 20:41 .
drwxr-x---+ 52 UserName  staff  1664 May 26 20:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  staff    96 Feb 24 12:44 state

I would just re-take ownership of ~/.local. It's not a standard folder on mac so you might have installed some program with sudo that created it. Either way, do sudo chown -R yourusername:staff ~/.local

Everything in your ~ (which is an alias for /Users/yourusername on Mac) should be owned by you by default, because this is your own user's home folder. It is your folder by definition.
The ~/.local folder is not a standard Mac folder. It was likely created when you installed other software like Vim. If you installed Vim or another program with sudo (which you generally shouldn't need to do) it might have created that folder as root.
To fix it, reset all the permissions on ~/.local to your own user with chown. The -R flag is recursive to apply to all child directories. Note staff is the default group on Mac OS.
sudo chown -R yourusername:staff ~/.local


What an answer. Thanks for a detailed explanation, you even explained what staff is.
